# Dropdown list validation based on another field's value in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I currently have the following 4 tables:

**Contacts**

```
Contact_ID,
ContactName
```

**Roles**

```
Role_ID,
Role
```

**Contact Roles**

```
ContactRole_ID,
Contact_ID,
Role_ID
```

**Events - Contacts**

```
EventContact_ID
Contact_ID
ContactRole_ID
```

My end goal is to limit the value that can be selected in the `ContactRole_ID` field of the **Events - Contacts** table based on the value selected in the `Contact_ID` field so that only Roles that the Contact is associated with will show up as options.  Is there a way to do that using SQL?

If any additional information or clarification is needed, please let me know. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do this using inner join with Contact Roles table and Events_Contacts table. Based on the column Contact_ID which is available in both the tables.

```
SELECT  EC.[EventContact_ID],EC.[Contact_ID],EC.[CotactRole_ID] 
FROM Contact_Roles CR INNER JOIN Events_Contacts EC ON
CR.Contact_ID=EC.Contact_ID
```

If I am right, for creating ms access form filter drop down you trying to do this??
If not, oops.. If you want to know more things based on this requirement in ms access, let me know. I will guide you.

Comment: So, I tried this, but maybe I did not implement it correctly.  When I tried that method, it limited my options to any role that any contact had.  So, if Contact 1 has a record for Role 1 and Role and Contact 2 has a record for Role 2 and Role 3, all three roles were showing up. But I only want the records to show up that apply to whatever contact is selected.

And I was trying to create in MS Access as a table filter/lookup value.  Is this more tailored toward a form filter drop down?  I envision basically the same way as like a country/state relationship would be.

Answer (score 0):

The recordsource of a dropdown list filtered by a another control value should look like this.
The "another control" can be a text box or a dropdown list also.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, ...etc
FROM table1 (JOIN more tables here if you want)
WHERE Field3 = Forms!Form_Name.Controls!Control1_Name
AND Field4 = Forms!Form_Name.Controls!Control2_Name(.value if required)
...
etc
```

Or you can save this as a query and use it where you need. Read **[this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-parameters-with-queries-and-reports-HA001117077.aspx),** it will help you a lot. This Access feature is very useful.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, this is to filter at the form level?  Is there a way to set this filter to operate at the table level as part of the lookup?

Comment: You can save this as a query and call it where you need. Have a look on this article. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-parameters-with-queries-and-reports-HA001117077.aspx

Comment: I have been reviewing that article, and I have to admit I am confused as to how it would apply in this situation.  So, I should create the above suggestion as a query, and then would I call that in the table lookup value?  Or how do I implement that to limit the options shown once a contact is selected?  Would that be like my parameter?  If so, how would I reference the value selected on the form to update the results returned by the subsequent field?